# Enable one specific shipping method for a specific user role only in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, shipping-method

I am trying to set up shipping rates, where only one specific shipping rate (flexible_shipping_single:10) is only available to one user role (Wholesaler - Wholesaler Role)

I have 3 Shipping methods (Royal Mail - flexible_shipping_single:10; Free shipping - free_shipping:1; International - flat_rate:2)

So if anyone other than Wholesaler visits my website they have free shipping and international shipping. If wholesaler visits the only have Royal Mail.

However, I am struggling to get this to work, here is the code I am using but I'm missing something.  I would be so great full for some help as I’m going round in circles.

Thank you so much

```
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Set the rate IDs in the array
    $rate_ids = array( 'flexible_shipping_single:10' );

    // NOT the required user role, remove shipping method(s)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'Wholesaler - Wholesaler Role' ) ) {
        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            // Checks if a value exists in an array
            if ( in_array( $rate_id, $rate_ids ) ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_id] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

*Updated*

First, you need to add the slug for "Wholesaler - Wholesaler Role" user role, not the name.

Then try the following revisited code version:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    global $current_user;

    // Here below define your custom user role SLUG
    $is_wholesaler = in_array('wwp_wholesaler', $current_user->roles);

    // Loop through shipping rates for this shipping package
    foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
        if ($is_wholesaler && in_array($rate_key, array('free_shipping:1', 'flat_rate:2'))) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        } elseif (!$is_wholesaler && $rate_key === 'flexible_shipping_single:10') {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Tested and works.

To refresh, cached shipping rates with those new settings, empty your cart...

Comment: When i try the above;  the ‘wwp_wholesaler’ is resulting in no shipping option available.  However if i change the order of my shipping methods the above works but the ‘customer’ shipping is showing no shipping option available.

Comment: thank you, still getting no shipping for wholesaler. Im not sure if there is a conflict with the wholesale plugin Im using or the shipping plugin.  Thank you for you help, I think I will have to rethink the shipping.